# Infinite loop while debugging a thread

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to attach a Hardware breakpoint to a game process and I succed. Then I'm trying to loop through the Exceptions and wait for the one that I've put in there, which is also working fine. The problem is that after it happens it goes into infinite loop that I cannot brake. Can you advise?
The reason for me doing that is that I want to stop the thread at this point, read the EAX value with the use of Context and then proceed with the process.

Header.h includes the functions that are called here and they all work fine, thus Im not including it at this point.

#include "Header.h"
   #include

int main() {

```
SetDebugPrivilege(TRUE);

DWORD dwProcessID = 0;
DWORD dwGame = 0;

printf("Looking for game process...\n");

while (dwProcessID == 0) {
    dwProcessID = GetProcessID(L"PathOfExile.exe");
    if (dwProcessID != 0)
        dwGame = 1;

    Sleep(100);
}

printf("dwProcessID = %p\n", dwProcessID);

HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, dwProcessID);
MODULEENTRY32 module;
module.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);
Module32First(snapshot, &module);

printf("PoE base address = %p\n", module.modBaseAddr);

hpChangeBreakpoint = (DWORD*)((char *)module.modBaseAddr + 0x1AAD20);

std::cout << hpChangeBreakpoint << std::endl;

//hpChangeBreakpoint = 0x013FB279;


HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, dwProcessID);

BOOL bDebugging = DebugActiveProcess(dwProcessID);
printf("bDebugging = %d\n", bDebugging);


DWORD dwThreadID = GetProcessThreadID(dwProcessID);

HANDLE hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwThreadID);

CONTEXT parentCtx;

parentCtx.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS;

if (GetThreadContext(hThread, &parentCtx))
{
    parentCtx.Dr0 = (DWORD)hpChangeBreakpoint;
    parentCtx.Dr7 = 0x00000001;

    std::cout << "GetThreadContext successful" << std::endl;

    SetThreadContext(hThread, &parentCtx);
}


DEBUG_EVENT DebugEvent;
DWORD dbgFlag = DBG_CONTINUE;
DWORD *currentHpPointerAddress = nullptr;
DWORD *maxHpPointerAddress = nullptr;
BOOLEAN bQuit = FALSE;

while (!bQuit && WaitForDebugEvent(&DebugEvent, INFINITE))
{
    dbgFlag = DBG_CONTINUE;

    switch (DebugEvent.dwDebugEventCode)
    {

    case EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT:

        switch (DebugEvent.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode)
        {

        case EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP:
            if (DebugEvent.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionAddress == (void*)hpChangeBreakpoint)
            {
                #define RESUME_FLAG 0x10000

                CONTEXT childContext;
                childContext.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
                if (GetThreadContext(hThread, &childContext))
                {
                    childContext.EFlags |= RESUME_FLAG;
                    SetThreadContext(hThread, &childContext);
                    std::cout << "current HP: " << childContext.Ecx << std::endl;

                    currentHpPointerAddress = (DWORD*)((char *)childContext.Edi + 0x8E0);
                    maxHpPointerAddress = (DWORD*)((char *)childContext.Edi + 0x8E4);

                }

                if (GetThreadContext(hThread, &parentCtx))
                {
                    parentCtx.Dr0 = 0;
                    parentCtx.Dr7 = 0x400;
                    SetThreadContext(hThread, &parentCtx);

                    bQuit = TRUE;

                }

            }
            else
                dbgFlag = DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED;

            break;

        default:
            dbgFlag = DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED;
        }


        break;

    case LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT:
    {
        CloseHandle(DebugEvent.u.LoadDll.hFile);
        break;
    }
    case CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT:
    {
        CloseHandle(DebugEvent.u.CreateProcessInfo.hFile);
        break;
    }
    case EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT:
        break;
    default:
        __nop();
    }

    if (!ContinueDebugEvent(DebugEvent.dwProcessId, DebugEvent.dwThreadId, dbgFlag))
    {
        break;
    }

    if (bQuit)
        DebugActiveProcessStop(dwProcessID);

}


while (1)
{
    WORD currentHP = 0;
    WORD maxHP = 0;
    if (
        ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, currentHpPointerAddress, &currentHP, sizeof(currentHP), NULL) == 0
        || ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, maxHpPointerAddress, &maxHP, sizeof(maxHP), NULL) == 0
        )
    {
        printf("Failed to read memory: %u\n", GetLastError());
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "HP: " << currentHP << " / " << maxHP << std::endl;
    }

    Sleep(1000);
}

system("pause>nul");
return 0;
```

}

When I run it, the game works fine until the breakpoint happens, when it does, i get infinite "breakpoint" cout's spam and when I debug it, this line:
                    if (DebugEvent.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionAddress == (void*)hpChangeBreakpoint)

is always true, but the dwFirstChance flag is 1, so its always a new exception? The only thing that changes in this infinite loop is the hThread, is always different. I feel like im missing something because of my lack of knowledge, thus would appreciate any help or hints to right direction. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you listen/know about `Resume Flag (RF)` ? you need set it for step over `DrX` brealpoint

so code must be next

```
#define RESUME_FLAG 0x10000

CONTEXT Context = {};
Context.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_CONTROL;// not need CONTEXT_FULL here;
if (GetThreadContext(hThread, &Context))
{
    Context.EFlags |= RESUME_FLAG; // !!! this line is key point
    SetThreadContext(hThread, &Context);
}
```

this will be work begin from win2003 or windows vista. unfortunately XP not let you set this flag in `CONTEXT`. so here you need remove `Dr0` breakpoint for step over it ( *or patch XP kernel - search for `0x003E0DD7` `DWORD` in ntoskrnl code and replace it to `0x003F0DD7` - this is `Eflags` mask - different in `RESUME_FLAG`* )

also let some optimization advice - you not need call `OpenThread` every time when `EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT`.

at first you already have this thread handle

```
HANDLE hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwThreadID);
```

simply not close it, after you call `SetThreadContext`

and exception can occur only in context of this thread, all other threads not affected by this.

at second you never close thread handle, opened in `EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT` - so you already have resource leaks.

debugger got thread handles on `CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT` and `CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT` and **MUST** close it (or just or usual maintain it and close on `EXIT_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT` and `EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT` )

you not handle `LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT` and as result not close file handle.

your code have **HUGE handle leaks** !

SuspendThread / ResumeThread - for what ?! absolute senseless - thread (and all threads in process) already suspended in this point

---

```
struct CThread : LIST_ENTRY
{
    HANDLE _hThread;
    ULONG _dwThreadId;

    CThread(HANDLE hThread, ULONG dwThreadId)
    {
        _hThread = hThread;
        _dwThreadId = dwThreadId;
    }

    ~CThread()
    {
        //CloseHandle(_hThread);// will be closed in ContinueDebugEvent
    }

    static CThread* get(ULONG dwThreadId, PLIST_ENTRY ThreadListHead, CThread* pHintThread)
    {
        if (pHintThread && pHintThread->_dwThreadId == dwThreadId)
        {
            return pHintThread;
        }

        PLIST_ENTRY entry = ThreadListHead;

        while ((entry = entry->Flink) != ThreadListHead)
        {
            pHintThread = static_cast<CThread*>(entry);

            if (pHintThread->_dwThreadId == dwThreadId)
            {
                return pHintThread;
            }
        }

        return 0;//??
    }

    static void DeleteAll(PLIST_ENTRY ThreadListHead)
    {
        PLIST_ENTRY entry = ThreadListHead->Flink;

        while (entry != ThreadListHead)
        {
            CThread* pThread = static_cast<CThread*>(entry);

            entry = entry->Flink;

            delete pThread;
        }
    }
};


void RunDebuggerLoop()
{
    BOOL bQuit = FALSE;

    LIST_ENTRY ThreadListHead = { &ThreadListHead, &ThreadListHead };

    CThread* pThread = 0;

    DEBUG_EVENT de;

    BOOLEAN bFirst = TRUE;

    while (!bQuit && WaitForDebugEvent(&de, INFINITE))
    {
        NTSTATUS status = DBG_CONTINUE;

        switch(de.dwDebugEventCode)
        {
        case EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT:
            if (
                !de.u.Exception.dwFirstChance 
                || 
                !(pThread = CThread::get(de.dwThreadId, &ThreadListHead, pThread))
                )
            {
                bQuit = TRUE;
                continue;
            }

            status = DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED;

            switch (de.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode)
            {
            case STATUS_BREAKPOINT:
            case STATUS_WX86_BREAKPOINT:
                if (bFirst)
                {
                    bFirst = FALSE;
                    status = DBG_CONTINUE;
                }
                break;

            case STATUS_SINGLE_STEP:
            case STATUS_WX86_SINGLE_STEP:
                {
                    ::CONTEXT ctx = {};
                    ctx.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_CONTROL;
                    if (GetThreadContext(pThread->_hThread, &ctx))
                    {
                        ctx.EFlags |= RESUME_FLAG;
                        SetThreadContext(pThread->_hThread, &ctx);
                    }
                }
                break;

            case STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION:
                if (de.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.NumberParameters > 1)
                {
                    ULONG_PTR ptr = de.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionInformation[1];
                }

                break;                              
            }

            break;

        case CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT:
            CloseHandle(de.u.CreateProcessInfo.hFile);
            //CloseHandle(de.u.CreateProcessInfo.hProcess);// will be auto closed in ContinueDebugEvent
            de.u.CreateThread.hThread = de.u.CreateProcessInfo.hThread;

        case CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT:
            if (pThread = new CThread(de.u.CreateThread.hThread, de.dwThreadId))
            {
                InsertHeadList(&ThreadListHead, pThread);
            }
            break;

        case EXIT_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT:
            if (pThread = CThread::get(de.dwThreadId, &ThreadListHead, pThread))
            {
                RemoveEntryList(pThread);
                delete pThread;
                pThread = 0;
            }
            break;

        case LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT:
            CloseHandle(de.u.LoadDll.hFile);
            break;

        case EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT:
            bQuit = TRUE;
            break;

        case OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING_EVENT:
        case UNLOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT:
            __nop();
            break;
        default:
            __nop();
        }

        if (!ContinueDebugEvent(de.dwProcessId, de.dwThreadId, status))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    CThread::DeleteAll(&ThreadListHead);
}
void Ep()
{
    // tag by * in begin of CommandLine
    PWSTR CommandLine = GetCommandLine();

    if (!CommandLine || *CommandLine != '*')
    {
        // debugger case

        WCHAR FileName[MAX_PATH];
        if (ULONG n = GetModuleFileName(0, FileName, RTL_NUMBER_OF(FileName)))
        {
            if (n < MAX_PATH)
            {
                PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
                STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
                PWSTR newCommandLine = (PWSTR)alloca((wcslen(CommandLine) + 2)*sizeof(WCHAR));
                *newCommandLine = '*';
                wcscpy(newCommandLine + 1, CommandLine);

                if (CreateProcessW(FileName, newCommandLine, 0, 0, 0, DEBUG_PROCESS, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
                {
                    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
                    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);

                    RunDebuggerLoop();
                }
            }
        }
        ExitProcess(0);
    }
    else
    {
        // main case

        wcscpy(CommandLine, CommandLine + 1);

        OutputDebugStringA("AAAAAA\n");

        if (MessageBoxW(0, L"xxx", CommandLine, MB_YESNO) == IDYES)
        {
            OutputDebugStringW(L"WWWWWWWW\n");
        }
        ExitProcess(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks for the time you've spent answering me. I'm sorry if some of the questions are weird, but Im a JS dev and what I'm doing here is my hobby. What i know is that it feels like a different and way deeper world then my JS.. ;)

I did edit the code, also removed what you've mentioned is redundant. The suspend/resume of the thread was there because between them I had some memory modyfications, but based on what you said, that the thread is suspended at this point anyway, even if I would modify the memory, there's no need for them?

Going back to the subject, the infinite loop is still here. Ive added the RF flag, but I'm just starting to read through the articles on that so apart from just adding it, I also understand why. Meanwhile, would you be so kind to give me another hint on why it might still not be working?
Also, I've added LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT handling and I'm closing the handler straight away as I don't need to do anything else with that at this point(do i?). What I dont entirely get is to when excatly should I close the handlers received from CREATE_PROCESS and CREATE_THREAD debug event? I'm trying to wrap my mind of how the debugger works, its my 4th day with it so far, but as i see it, this is what happens:

WaitForDebugEvent receives a debug event, as long as its not mine, its being handled by ContinueDebugEvent with DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED, so its being passed back and the game handles it.
Finally WaitForDebugEvent receives my debug event, which is EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP, I do my stuff in there and then makes it continue with DBG_CONTINUE - that flags the exception as handled by me, and system just keeps going after it. Is that correct?

My actual code that still loops and prints "Breakpoint" in infinite loop:

```
#include "Header.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {


hpChangeBreakpoint = 0x013FB279;

SetDebugPrivilege(TRUE);

DWORD dwProcessID = 0;
DWORD dwGame = 0;

printf("Looking for game process...\n");

while (dwProcessID == 0) {
    dwProcessID = GetProcessID(L"PathOfExile.exe");
    if (dwProcessID != 0)
        dwGame = 1;

    Sleep(100);
}

printf("dwProcessID = %p\n", dwProcessID);

HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, dwProcessID);

BOOL bDebugging = DebugActiveProcess(dwProcessID);
printf("bDebugging = %d\n", bDebugging);


DWORD dwThreadID = GetProcessThreadID(dwProcessID);

HANDLE hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwThreadID);

CONTEXT context;

context.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS;

if (GetThreadContext(hThread, &context))
{
    context.Dr0 = hpChangeBreakpoint;
    context.Dr7 = 0x00000001;

    std::cout << "GetThreadContext successful" << std::endl;

    SetThreadContext(hThread, &context);
}


DEBUG_EVENT DebugEvent;
BOOL bContinueDebugging = false;



for(;;)
{
    WaitForDebugEvent(&DebugEvent, INFINITE);

    switch (DebugEvent.dwDebugEventCode)
    {

    case EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT:

        switch (DebugEvent.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode)
        {
        case EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP:
            if (DebugEvent.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionAddress == (void*)hpChangeBreakpoint)
            {
                #define RESUME_FLAG 0x10000
                CONTEXT Context;
                Context.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_CONTROL;
                Context.EFlags |= RESUME_FLAG;


                std::cout << "Breakpoint" << std::endl;

                bContinueDebugging = true;
            }
            if (bContinueDebugging)
            {
                // DBG_CONTINUE to tell the program we have handled the exception
                ContinueDebugEvent(DebugEvent.dwProcessId, DebugEvent.dwThreadId, DBG_CONTINUE);
                bContinueDebugging = false;
            }
            else // if the exception was not handled by our exception-handler, we want the program to handle it, so..
                ContinueDebugEvent(DebugEvent.dwProcessId, DebugEvent.dwThreadId, DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED);

            break;
        default:
            ContinueDebugEvent(DebugEvent.dwProcessId, DebugEvent.dwThreadId, DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED);
        }


        break;

    case LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT:
    {
        std::cout << "load dll debug event" << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(DebugEvent.u.LoadDll.hFile);
        break;
    }
    default:
        ContinueDebugEvent(DebugEvent.dwProcessId, DebugEvent.dwThreadId, DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED);
    }

}

system("pause>nul");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: "Going back to the subject, the infinite loop is still here. Ive added the RF flag" - but you not call "SetThreadContext" !! what sense simply initialize `CONTEXT Context` - without call "SetThreadContext" - fix this first, for resolve main issue. if you not run under XP. "that the thread is suspended at this point anyway" - before you call ContinueDebugEvent - all process is suspended - you not need call `SuspendThread` / `ResumeThread`

"even if I would modify the memory, there's no need for them?" - yes, not need

Comment: Oh my dog, so obvious :) Let me get on it, will let you know! thanks alot RbMm!

Comment: It looks like it goes through mate! :) Thank you! There's another issue thou - after passing this exception, there is an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION, if i dont handle it, after 2nd try it crashes the app. Can it be related to what I'm doing?

Comment: yes, my mistake :) I forget say you call GetThreadContext(hThread, &context); too :)

Comment: i update self code snippet. you not intitialize `CONTEXT Context ` structure before call `SetThreadContext` as result in `Context.Eip` garbage from your stack (`0xcccccccc` value )

Comment: It's working! I love that feeling when it finally does :-) Can't thank you enough RbMm. Would you be so kind to help me close the handles correctly so I have an example? I dont know if its just me but that debug enviroment is confusing. Ill paste my current code underneath.

Comment: Ive updated the first code snippet so I dont repeat the same thing. There's a list of DEBUG_EVENTS just being handled by ContinueDebugEvent, that was for me to find out which one was causing the issue :)

Comment: Hi again @RbMm :) I've again updated the snippet. Im getting the value from the pointer like i wanted, thank you for that. Im also successfuly escaping the debugging loop - after I get the pointer i want it moved to the second while loop, which is displaying the hp every second. The only problem thats left is that after some short time, 5-15 secs, the game freezes, even without me toggling my breakpoint (which doesnt exist anymore anyway). It feels like the debugger stopped at something that I'm not aware of, any idea?

Comment: but you not call `DebugActiveProcessStop` - as result first debug event - DLL load or new thread creation - and make this freeze - game send event to the debugger object and wait when you call `ContinueDebugEvent` - you **must** call `DebugActiveProcessStop` for stop debugging

Comment: Im calling it here -> if (!ContinueDebugEvent(DebugEvent.dwProcessId, DebugEvent.dwThreadId, dbgFlag))
    {
        DebugActiveProcessStop(dwProcessID);
        break;
    } <- is that a wrong place for that?

Comment: of course wrong. you need call it direct, but not on error

Comment: use bQuit variable for break look (now you not use it, only senseless). when you decide exit - set `bQuit = true`and call `DebugActiveProcessStop`. loop must be `while(!bQuit && Wait..)`

Comment: Its stupid how something becomes so obvious only after someone points it out! :) Everything works perfectly, thank you mate!